# HttpUtility.HtmlEncode doesn't encode everything

Tags: c#, html, encoding, utf-8

I am interacting with a web server using a desktop client program in C# and .Net 3.5. I am using Fiddler to see what traffic the web browser sends, and emulate that. Sadly this server is old, and is a bit confused about the notions of charsets and utf-8. Mostly it uses Latin-1.

When I enter data into the Web browser containing "special" chars, like "Ω π ℵ ∞ ♣ ♥
♈ ♉ ♊ ♋ ♌ ♍ ♎ ♏ ♐ ♑ ♒ ♓" fiddler show me that they are being transmitted as follows from browser to server: `"&#9800; &#9801; &#9802; &#9803; &#9804; &#9805; &#9806; &#9807; &#9808; &#9809; &#9810; &#9811; "`

But for my client, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode does not convert these characters, it leaves them as is. What do I need to call to convert "♈" to &#9800; and so on?

Comment: Strangely, .Net 2.0's HttpUtility will properly encode characters between 0xA0 and 0xFF, but not those above!  (Check it out using Reflector.)

Comment: Strange. HttpUtility.HtmlEncode (all overloads) call HttpEncoder.Current.HtmlEncode, so it seems that the encoder used depends on the value of HttpEncoder.Current, concerning which: "If a derived HttpEncoder type is specified in the configuration file, the Current property returns a reference to the custom type. However, if no custom encoder is used, the property returns a reference to the default ASP.NET HttpEncoder instance. The Current property is not thread-safe. Set this property only in the application's Application_Start method, because Application_Start runs on a single thread."

Comment: I believe the reason for this is that those characters are not illegal if the character set specified for the document allows them. HtmlEncode is meant to remove dangerous characters, not encode every character that could be encoded. The letter A can be encoded like this as well, but there's no need to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems horribly inefficient, but the only way I can think to do that is to look through each character:

```
public static string MyHtmlEncode(string value)
{
   // call the normal HtmlEncode first
   char[] chars = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(value).ToCharArray();
   StringBuilder encodedValue = new StringBuilder();
   foreach(char c in chars)
   {
      if ((int)c > 127) // above normal ASCII
         encodedValue.Append("&#" + (int)c + ";");
      else
         encodedValue.Append(c);
   }
   return encodedValue.ToString();
}
```

Comment: `Server.HtmlEncode` and `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` wouldn't encode [this character: ’](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm), but this solution worked.

Comment: This might fail for surrogate pairs like [GRINNING FACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f600/index.htm).  You might need to somehow use methods like [Char.IsHighSurrogate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcwwfbb8(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: "horribly inefficient" "look trough each character" this is how `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` works, expect it use a char pointer and `StringWriter`.

Answer (score 15):

Rich Strahl just posted a blog post, [Html and Uri String Encoding without System.Web](http://west-wind.com/weblog/posts/617930.aspx), where he has some custom code that encodes the upper range of characters, too.

```
/// <summary>
/// HTML-encodes a string and returns the encoded string.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="text">The text string to encode. </param>
/// <returns>The HTML-encoded text.</returns>
public static string HtmlEncode(string text)
{
    if (text == null)
        return null;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text.Length);

    int len = text.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        switch (text[i])
        {

            case '<':
                sb.Append("&lt;");
                break;
            case '>':
                sb.Append("&gt;");
                break;
            case '"':
                sb.Append("&quot;");
                break;
            case '&':
                sb.Append("&amp;");
                break;
            default:
                if (text[i] > 159)
                {
                    // decimal numeric entity
                    sb.Append("&#");
                    sb.Append(((int)text[i]).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                    sb.Append(";");
                }
                else
                    sb.Append(text[i]);
                break;
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: You're forgetting single quote `'`. Encode that! `<tag name='oops' i'm in here wrecking your tag'>`

Comment: I back my words up. [Mono source code](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Util/HttpEncoder.cs#L264-L271)

Comment: The cut-off should be `126` not `159` as ASCII only covers 128 characters (and the 127th character is the non-printable "Delete" control character).

Answer (score 13):

The return value type of HtmlEncode is a string, which is of Unicode and hence has not need to encode these characters.

If the encoding of your output stream is not compatible with these characters then use HtmlEncode like this:-

```
 HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(outgoingString, Response.Output);
```

HtmlEncode with then escape the characters appropriately.

Comment: Interesting, but how would you tie that up with Scott H's posting technique from http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=43e49ec8-1fa7-44c1-8177-42cd4fead8db

Comment: @Anthony:  They don't tie up at all (did you post the right link?). HtmlEncode has nothing to do with form POST emulations, or were you thinking of URLEncode stuff, thats a different thing.

Comment: @ AnthonyWJones yes, it's the right link for the post technique. I have to encode this way before I post the form.

Comment: @Anthony: ok. So the answer to your first question is as stated, They don't tie up.  The encoding you need to post with is URL Encoding which is unrelated to HTML encoding.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm pretty sure that for this particular server, I need HTML encoding before posting.

Comment: @Anthony: It may well be for some strange reason the server is expecting HTML content in the entity body.  However standard HTML forms will send data using the encoding that you would find in a url query string.

Comment: Encoding depends on the value of HttpEncoder.Current, as one can see by looking at the source code of either overload of HttpUtility.HtmlEncode.  "If a derived HttpEncoder type is specified in the configuration file, the Current property returns a reference to the custom type. However, if no custom encoder is used, the property returns a reference to the default ASP.NET HttpEncoder instance.  The Current property is not thread-safe. Set this property only in the application's Application_Start method, because Application_Start runs on a single thread."

Answer (score 4):

The AntiXSS library from Microsoft correctly encodes these characters.

[AntiXSS on Codeplex](http://wpl.codeplex.com/)

[Nuget package](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/AntiXSS) (best way to add as a reference)

Comment: Note that there is still a big difference, while HttpUtility.UrlEncode correctly encodes ÄÖÜß, AntiXssEncoder does not, unless you want named entities.

Comment: This library has a bad habit of destroying emoji characters, like .

Answer (score 2):

It seems like HtmlEncode is just for encoding strings that are put into HTML documents, where only / < > & etc. cause problems. For URL's, just replace HtmlEncode with UrlEncode.

Comment: No, UrlEncode is also horrible. For eg. + isn't converted to %2b.

Answer (score 1):

@bdukes response above will do the job, but we can make it much faster if we assume that most characters will *not* be in this range.  Note the quoted 'Ā' (unicode 0x0100)

```
/// <summary>.Net 2.0's HttpUtility.HtmlEncode will not properly encode
/// Unicode characters above 0xFF.  This may be fixed in newer 
/// versions.</summary>
public static string HtmlEncode(string s)
{
    // Let .Net 2.0 get right what it gets right.
    s = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(s);

    // Search for first non-ASCII.  Hopefully none and we can just 
    // return s.
    int num = IndexOfHighChar(s, 0);
    if (num == -1)
        return s;
    int old_num = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    do {
        sb.Append(s, old_num, num - old_num);
        sb.Append("&#");
        sb.Append(((int)s[num]).ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));
        sb.Append(';');
        old_num = num + 1;
        num = IndexOfHighChar(s, old_num);
    } while (num != -1);
    sb.Append(s, old_num, s.Length - old_num);
    return sb.ToString();
}

static unsafe int IndexOfHighChar(string s, int start)
{
    int num = s.Length - start;
    fixed (char* str = s) {
        char* chPtr = str + start;
        while (num > 0) {
            char ch = chPtr[0];
            if (ch >= 'Ā')
                return s.Length - num;
            chPtr++;
            num--;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always replace the unwanted ASCII as follows: When this is encoded without the if statement the result string is "This means I am crying :'&'#39;) For whatever reason 'special characters' are handled and replaced with HTML char.

```
string text = "This means I am crying :'(";

string encoded = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(text);
if(encoded.Contains("&#39;"))
{
    encoded = encoded.Replace("&#39;", "'");
}
```