# Decoding minus from html

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am reading some og tags from sites but I can't seem to decode minus(-) from encoded string.
I tried with `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` and `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` but none of them seem to work. I get `&#8211;` instead on minus.

What is the case with this?

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547634/httputility-htmlencode-doesnt-encode-everything

Comment: @AndreiSchneider Thanks, that should do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is not minus (`-`), it's a dash (`–`) which is not the same thing. It's a different character.

Comment: I Couldn't remember how it's said in English.