# Why html escape >159?

Tags: html, .net, http, encoding, mono

When I comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/547663/34537) about forgetting to escape `'` I linked [mono sources](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Util/HttpEncoder.cs#L264-L271). Why on earth do they encode when the character is >159 && <256?

Comment: I wonder if this might fit better as a meta question...?

Comment: no, it would be a metaquestion if he was asking about stackoverflow, but he's asking about Mono

Answer (score 2):

Escaping characters with code number greater than 159 might be a safety measure against potential character encoding issues. Such characters have different representations in different widely used character encodings.

It does not sound rational, since the same applies to characters with code number greater than 127. But the plausible answer to the “why on earth do they encode” question is that they are afraid of having character data munged due to encoding mismatches (data is created in one encoding but processed as if it were in another encoding).