# how to replace &lsquo;

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string which I'm html encoding, then using a string builder to allow certain html characters. All works fine except for the left sided quote `&lsquo;`. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
StringBuilder htmlStr = new StringBuilder();
htmlStr.Append(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(reader["NewsDetail"]));
htmlStr.Replace("&lt;p&gt;", "<p>");
htmlStr.Replace("&lt;/p&gt;", "</p>");
htmlStr.Replace("&lsquo;", "‘");
```

Comment: In what way isn't it working?

Comment: &lsquo; isn't a standard ASCII character. Could it be your HTML is encoded as ASCII, rather than UTF-8?

Comment: @DavidArno it simply isn't replacing the character. Same thing happens with `&rsquo;`

Comment: When you say "it simply isn't replacing the character", do you mean it's not matching "&lsquo;", it's replacing it with "" (empty string) or replacing it with something else?

Comment: Are you sure your encoded text contains `&lsquo;`? Could it be `&amp;lsquo;`?

Comment: Yes my error, It is in fact `&amp;rsquo;` thanks for the help, that's been annoying me all morning.

Answer (score 2):

This char is not encoded by HtmlEncode.

```
string h = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("<p>‘test’</p>");
Console.WriteLine(h);
// output: &lt;p&gt;‘test’&lt;/p&gt;
```

If you need to encode you will have to do it yourself. Check this post:
[HttpUtility.HtmlEncode doesn't encode everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547634/httputility-htmlencode-doesnt-encode-everything)